# Ajax not calling PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a problem with ajax calling a PHP code without change current page. In the php_error.log there is no reference to the PHP file. I have no errors on screen or anything to guide me to resolve the problem.

This is my javascript function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getMail(){
                var name = $('#username').val();
                var dominio = $('#dominio').val();
                if(name.trim() == '' ){
                    alert('Ingrese su nombre de usuario.');
                    $('#username').focus();
                    return false;
                }else{
                    $.ajax({
                        type:'POST',
                        url:'paginas/recover.php',
                        //data:'username='+name+'&dominio='+dominio,
                        beforeSend: function () {
                            $('.nextBtn').attr("disabled","disabled");
                            $('.modal-body').css('opacity', '.5');
                        },
                        success:function(msg){
                            $('#username').val('');                                           
                            $('.nextBtn').removeAttr("disabled");
                            $('.modal-body').css('opacity', '');
                        },                      
                    });

                }
            };
</script>
```

This is the function calling button from the HTML

```
<button id="nextBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" onclick="getMail()" disabled>Continuar</button>
```

And this is the PHP code

```
<?php
    //include ('../paginas/header.php');
    include ('../paginas/funciones.php');
    //$dominio = $_GET['dominio'];
    //$usr = $_GET['username'];
    //getToken($usr,$dominio);
    $to_mail = 'mail@gmail.com';//getMail($usr, $dominio);
    $to_name = 'Usuario Prueba';
    $message = 'Prueba';
    $subject = 'Prueba';
    sendMail($to_mail,$to_name,$subject,$message);      
?>
```

If I access the PHP file alone, the mail was sent,  but when I use the javascript function, nothing happened. The function was invoked because if I don't complete the username in the form the alert was executed.

Thanks

Comment: To start, `type:'POST'` should be `method:'POST'` - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Can you please explain why the URL is `'paginas/recover.php'`, yet inside that very file you include a path to `'../paginas/funciones.php'`? do you have two folders with the same name?

Comment: Obviously a `" disabled>` button doesn't do anything no..

Comment: Are you sending a response back to the ajax call after processing? does your sendMail has a return?

Comment: No error on the console from that ajax call? You need to send something back to the script to tell it that it was executed properly or not. Worst case, use something like ChromePhp to help you debug what happens in your PHP code if it's being called but just fails. It shouldn't fail though because it runs by itself and you're not passing any parameters to it...

Comment: In console the error was `SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'ajax'`. And the line was were appears the `}else{`

Answer (score 0):

//data:'username='+name+'&dominio='+dominio,

change above line to this make it uncomment  and pass data as blank

data:'',

Comment: open console > and go to network see your ajax call occur or not

Comment: In console the error was `SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'ajax'`. And the line was were appears the `}else{`